# How to execute Metrics2 plugin from command line?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, metrics, code-metrics

Is it possible to run [Metrics Plugin](http://metrics2.sourceforge.net/) from Command Line.

I am not interested in Ant Task. What I am looking for is to run this from a shell script passing the file name as a parameter and to get the output metrics on stdout

Is it possible to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can.  Metrics2 is designed to work in an Eclipse environment, and is highly dependent on Eclipse functionality.  All output goes to a table in Eclipse.  Metrics2 is open source, so you may be able to contribute something useful there.